# Convert cookies to scope values

Tags: xpages

How do I access the cookies and make them into scope variables? I can get the cookies but I am at a loss for how/when/where to create scope variables for each one once I have them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is how early you can get the cookies. I don't know if the map is filled at `beforePageLoad` or `afterPageLoad`. From there you can iterate the map (use `keySet()`) and create / update in `sessionScope` or `viewScope`. You just need to bear in mind `sessionScope` may be shared across browser tabs.

Comment: Thank you. I have it figured out now

Answer (score 0):

For that matter you could just move the entire cookie map to a scoped variable. Not quite as usable when you need to access them. I assume you just need to find one or two cookies? You just need to get those values and move them where you want like Paul said.

Comment: Actually this application has dozens of fields filled in from cookies and we are moving specific ones to viewScope variables upon opening of specific pages instead. So the trick is to be able to selectively select those that need to be used and ignore those that don't until a different page is opened.